# How do I open a modal by clicking any of say 100 boxes with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

This opens the modal when clicking on the first element with the class "today". How can I make it open when clicking all elements with class "today"?

```
// Get the modal and the open-modal-button
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "block";}

      <tr>
        <td class="rowspan" rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
        <td class="today"></td>
      </tr>
```

***Updated***
Figuring this out: The 100 boxes now open the modal and I'd like the button I have added to the modal to color the element which was clicked.

I unfortunately have no clue how to do this except thinking of the using "This" ?!!?

Code now looks like this:

```
// Get the modal and the open-modal-buttons
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("today");
var btnsLength = btns.length

for (var i = 0; i < btnsLength; i++) {
btns[i].onclick = function () {
modal.style.display = "block";
};
}

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
      <button id="color"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you defined **btn** only for the first element of all elements with the class "today". The **[0]** at the end of the lines defines this: `var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0];` removing the zero should answer your question.

Comment: @GerritHalfmann thanks for answering. I couldnt open the modal at all without the "[0]", adding the "[0]" was a win for me - next objective is now for me to do what I asked in the post. :)

Comment: Check the latest answer, some else figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **the return value of [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is an HTML collection**, **you should iterate through it and add the `onclick` event to each of their elements**.

In order to do this, you should first get all elements with `class="today"` by your selector `document.getElementsByClassName('today')`, so it will return an HTML collection (which is an array-like object) of all your element with `class="today"`. Then you should iterate through them with a traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop or [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/forEach).

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("today");

var btnsLength = btns.length;

for (var i = 0; i < btnsLength; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.today {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowspan" rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td class="today">2</td>
      <td class="today">3</td>
      <td class="today">4</td>
      <td class="today">5</td>
      <td class="today">6</td>
      <td class="today">7</td>
      <td class="today">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="today">9</td>
      <td class="today">10</td>
      <td class="today">11</td>
      <td class="today">12</td>
      <td class="today">13</td>
      <td class="today">14</td>
      <td class="today">15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="modal">Element with today class is clicked!</div>
```

### UPDATE

According to your updated question, in order to access the property which fires the event, you should use [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) interface, with the `target` property within it, to get which element fires the event. So you should pass `event` into your function and whenever the function get invoked you have the targeted element in your function too.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("today");

var btnsLength = btns.length;

for (var i = 0; i < btnsLength; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function(event) {
    event.target.style.color = 'red';
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.today {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowspan" rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td class="today">2</td>
      <td class="today">3</td>
      <td class="today">4</td>
      <td class="today">5</td>
      <td class="today">6</td>
      <td class="today">7</td>
      <td class="today">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="today">9</td>
      <td class="today">10</td>
      <td class="today">11</td>
      <td class="today">12</td>
      <td class="today">13</td>
      <td class="today">14</td>
      <td class="today">15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="modal">Element with today class is clicked!</div>
```

Comment: Looks good! I would go more into details what the javascript section does

Comment: @SMAKSS thats it. Thank you. Next up. Having the modal respond to the element that was clicked. ;)

Comment: @SMAKSS Yes, Im trying to color the element which fired the modal using a button in the modal.

Comment: @SMAKSS Nope, I didnt know I could only chose one. And since they were both good I wanted to appreciate both. :) I changed it back to yours. Obviously Im new here. ;)

Comment: @Daniel It's ok, no worries at all, welcome to the community. For doing such a thing you should use [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface. I will update the answer to fits your actual need but make sure you update your question with your new desire. Also for appreciation, you can use upvotes. For more information, you can read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @SMAKSS If I can get it to work ill even cast a lucky charm on you... after upvoting ofc ;)

Answer (score 1):

`var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0];` will return only the first element. You can get all of them removing `[0]`:

`var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("today");`

and given it is a list, you can iterate through it with a for loop:

```
for (var btn of btns) {
      btn.onclick = function() { modal.style.display = "block";};
    }
```

or with a `forEach`:

```
btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "block";});
```